# What gets put on a thread pool thread in Task when using async/await?

Tags: c#, multithreading, threadpool

Please consider the following code

```
    public static async Task<int> Answer()
    {
        await Task.Delay(1000);
        return 42;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 20; j++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(j +" " + Thread.CurrentThread.IsThreadPoolThread);
            if (j == 1)
            {
                new Task( async ()=>
                    {
                        int answer = await Answer();
                        Console.WriteLine(answer + " " + Thread.CurrentThread.IsThreadPoolThread);
                    }).Start();
            }

            Thread.Sleep(200);
        }

        return;
```

Can you guess what the `CurrentThread.IsThreadPoolThread` when printing answer is?

It appears that `Task.Delay(..)` is doing it, for if I remove await, then the answer is `False`. However, I can not seem to find that `Delay` actually puts stuff on the thread pool in the documentation.

This brings me to the more general question. What in Task *does* actually start up a thread pool thread besides `Run(..)`?

**Edit:**
Replacing `new Task(...)` with `Ask()`

```
    public static async void Ask()
    {
        int answer = await Answer();
        Console.WriteLine(answer + " " + Thread.CurrentThread.IsThreadPoolThread);
    }
```

yields the same result

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I describe in my [`async` / `await` intro](http://nitoprograms.blogspot.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) post, by default `await` will capture the current "context" and use that to execute the continuation (the code after the `await`). This "context" is `SynchronizationContext.Current` unless it is `null`, in which case it is `TaskScheduler.Current`.

I also describe [using `async` on Console apps](http://nitoprograms.blogspot.com/2012/02/async-console-programs.html) on my blog. Console apps do not provide a `SynchronizationContext`, so the "context" falls back to `TaskScheduler.Current`. Since the currently-executing `Task` is running on the thread pool, `TaskScheduler.Current` is the same as `TaskScheduler.Default`, which is the thread pool task scheduler.

This is why your code is resuming on a thread pool thread. It's the correct behavior.

Comment: So _not_ having a context, will _always_ make the callback run on a TP thread? Does this also include `Task.ConfigureAwait(false)`, i.e., setting to false will _always_ execute the callback on a TP thread?

Comment: Actually, I'm not sure I fully understand "Since the currently-executing Task is running on the thread pool". Why is the Task running on the thread pool?

Comment: When you say `new Task` ... `Start` without supplying a `TaskScheduler`, it will run on a thread pool; this is very similar to `Task.Run`. And yes, if you `await` an operation (that is not already completed) using `ConfigureAwait(false)`, then it will always execute the continuation on the thread pool.

Comment: I have edited the post replacing the `new Task.Start(..)`. The result is the same. I presume that this is because the call to `Task.Start(..)` is now implicit. Is the conclusion that _usually_ all tasks get to run on the thread pool without an explicit request to do so? Do you think it would be possible to make the call to `Answer(..)` blocking?

Comment: With the new code, `Answer` starts executing on the Console app main thread, which still doesn't have a `SynchronizationContext` or `TaskScheduler`, so it will still use `TaskScheduler.Default`. This is why you're seeing the same result, which is still correct. There is no implicit call to `Task.Start`.

Comment: And yes, you could make `Answer` blocking by just doing `Answer().Wait()`. But it's *usually* a [really bad idea](http://nitoprograms.blogspot.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html), as I explain on my blog.

Comment: I see. So had the same code been a say winforms app, there would indeed have been when calling answer, because the `SynchronizationContext` would be the UI thread itself?

Comment: Yes; UI apps do provide a `SynchronizationContext` that schedules work to the UI thread.